# SQL Server : update a record foreign key references to another

Tags: sql-server

Due to data migration issue, there are duplicated records in Table A.

Table A has two rows with same name "Jason", with id 1 and 3. I would like to move all the foreign key references from id = 3 in Link A & Link B to 1, then delete the record of Jason with id = 3 from Table A.

**Table A**

```
id     name       column2    column3
-------------------------------------
 1     Jason        text      text
 2     Alice        text      text
 3     Jason        text      text
```

**Link A**

```
id     column1     tableA_ID
----------------------------
 1        text        1     
 2        text        2      
 3        text        3
```

**Link B**

```
id     column1     tableA_ID
----------------------------
 1        text        1     
 2        text        3      
 3        text        2
```

For now, my simple solution would be

```
--update ids
UPDATE db_A.`Link_A` SET id = 1 WHERE tableA_ID = 3;
UPDATE db_A.`Link_B` SET id = 1 WHERE tableA_ID = 3;
--delete ids
DELETE db_A.`Table_A` WHERE id = 3;
```

The production server has tons of affected Ids, so I'm thinking if there is a better solution out there.

Answer (score 0):

I would get the values you need to update into a temp table and use that to do all the updates. You could use a CTE or sub-query, but having it in a # table seems convenient to me and simplifies the updates. So do this first and then use the # table to do the updates:

```
select a.id originalId, b.minId updatedId
  from Table_A  a
  join (select name, min(id) minId
          from Table_A
         group by name
         having count(*) > 1)  b on a.name = b.name
                                and a.id != b.minId
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your DDL in temporary tables and this solution looks fine.
You just need to do the same for tbl B and it should work. In any case, please, verify first in copies of your production tables:

```
-- Added DDL for my tables to allow easy testing to everybody:
SELECT * INTO #tblA 
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS ID, 'Jason' AS [Name], 'text' AS column2, 'text' AS column3
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS ID, 'Alice' AS [Name], 'text' AS column2, 'text' AS column3
    UNION
    SELECT 3 AS ID, 'Jason' AS [Name], 'text' AS column2, 'text' AS column3
) T1;

SELECT * INTO #tblLinkA 
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS ID, 'text' AS column1, 1 AS tableA_ID
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS ID, 'text' AS [Name], 2 AS tableA_ID
    UNION
    SELECT 3 AS ID, 'text' AS [Name], 3 AS tableA_ID
) T1;

SELECT * FROM #tblA;
SELECT * FROM #tblLinkA;
WITH DUP AS (
SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, column2, column3 ORDER BY ID) AS Row,
    MIN(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Name, column2, column3) AS ID_Related
    FROM #tblA) -- SELECT * FROM Dup ORDER BY ID;
UPDATE #tblLinkA
    SET #tblLinkA.tableA_ID = DUP.ID_Related
    FROM DUP
    WHERE  #tblLinkA.tableA_ID = DUP.ID
      and DUP.Row > 1;

WITH DUP AS (
SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, column2, column3 ORDER BY ID) AS Row,
    MIN(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Name, column2, column3) AS ID_Related
    FROM #tblA)
DELETE FROM DUP 
    WHERE Row > 1;
SELECT * FROM #tblA;
SELECT * FROM #tblLinkA;
```